# Jquery math within function

Tags: jquery, math

I'm trying to multiply and input amount by 3.5%, Can anyone give me any ideas how to do it?

```
$("#invest_amount").keyup(function() {

         $('#fee').val($('#invest_amount').val() + 3.5);

        });
```

Comment: You write in your question that you want to multiply, yet you write `+` in your code instead of multiplication.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to parse the input first then use `*` to multiply, not `+`, for example:

```
$("#invest_amount").keyup(function() {
  $('#fee').val(parseFloat($('#invest_amount').val()) * .035);
});
```

or...

```
$("#invest_amount").keyup(function() {
  $('#fee').val(+$('#invest_amount').val() * .035);
});
```

[`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) returns a string, so you need to use `+` or `praseFloat()` to convert it to a number first

Comment: Do you know how I can use .toFixed(2)with this? Its not working for me?

Comment: @user534830 - like this: `$('#fee').val((+$('#invest_amount').val() * .035).toFixed(2));`

Comment: If you're multiplying, there's actually no need to force the coercion with `+` because `*` will do it for you, e.g. `$('#fee').val(($('#invest_amount').val() * .035).toFixed(2));`

Answer (score 3):

You need to [parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) the value first:

```
var value = parseFloat($('#invest_amount').val());
if (!isNaN(value)) {
    $('#fee').val(value * 0.035);
} else {
    alert('The entered value is not a valid number');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$( '#fee' ).val( $( '#invest_amount' ).val() * .035 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Knowing mathematics, and the significance of mathematical symbols, seems to be a basic prerequisite for your problem. Read more about mathematics here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematics